# Reorder Umbraco to have Articles/Year/Month/Article map structure

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, doctype, maintainability

I have a website that's been running for over a year. The overview is getting lost in the Articles doctype and I've been asked to change the file structure from Articles/Article to Articles/Year/Month/Article.

In short, the admin opens Umbraco and sees the Articles and clicks the arrow to see all the articles. It then takes a couple of minutes since the are all loaded. Instead I want a map structure that devides the articles into year and month published.

Since i'm talking about 5k articles, I can't really do this manually.

Any advice?

Comment: you can hire a freelancer to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do 2 things:

1. Create a simple script which moves all articles into a year/month folder structure. Should be pretty simple to make.
2. Add a List View content type on your **"Articles"** template. It will give a searchable list with all 5K articles. It will prevent the loadtime in Umbraco UI. You can see how the list view works here: http://www.robertgray.net.au/posts/a-first-look-at-umbraco-container-content-types

Comment: Why would you create a folder structure based on information that is already linked to the article. Making any future changes to this URL structure equally complex. Permalinks were designed for CMSs for a reason...

Comment: @GerardWilkinson Because Umbraco backoffice is slow when you try to open a folder with 5000 child nodes. Your solution does not help the CMS user..

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the UrlProvider and ContentFinder configuration in your umbraco instance.

Shouldn't require any manual editing of the articles provided they were posted on the days you would like them to display as.

Take a look at this: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/urlprovider-and-contentfinder/